# Save combox value in file using c#

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox, streamreader

I'm writing a little program, which displays my to do's, the priority etc. In this program I got 2 tabs: tab 1 is for create a new to do and the other tab is for displaying the current to do's. So when I put in some text into a textbox in tab 1 and after I click a "Save" button, it should save it in the tab2's combobox. And when I restart the program, it should still be saved. Google told me to do this with a file so I can save it into a file. And I found a short code, which I adjusted for my program. Here you can see my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check if directory exists
    if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\)"))
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    else
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\");
    }

    if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt"))
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    else
    {
        File.Create(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt");
    }

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt");
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        combox_Name2.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine());
    }
    sr.Close();
}

private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt", true);

    try
    {
        Process.Start(combox_Name2.Text, txt_Name.Text);

        if (combox_Name2.Items.Contains(txt_Name.Text))
        {
            // Do nothing
        }

        else
        {
            writer.WriteLine(combox_Name2.Text);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Dispose();
            combox_Name2.Items.Add(txt_Name.Text);
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The file '" + txt_Name.Text + "' could not be located", "File could not be located");
    }
}
```

And my problem now is: Everytime I start the program, put some text into the textbox and click on save button, there comes an error on line

`StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt");`

VS2012 say that the process can't get on `C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt` because it's already started in another process.

Can someone give me a hint?

Cheers

Comment: `if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt"))` results in `Not Exists`, do nothing doesn't do anything :)

Comment: Thanks I edited my code so there is no `// do nothing` anymore :) but thats not the reason :o^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code will achieve your objective. Do mark as answer if it works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace FileHandling
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Check if directory exists
        if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\)"))
        {
            // Do nothing
        }

        else
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\");
        }

        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt"))
        {
            // Do nothing
        }

        else
        {
            File.Create(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt");
        }

        using (StreamReader writer = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt"))
        {
            while (writer.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                combox_Name2.Items.Add(writer.ReadLine());
            }
            writer.Close();
        }

    }

    private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt", true))
        {
            try
            {
                if (combox_Name2.Items.Contains(txt_Name.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The task '" + txt_Name.Text + "' already exist in list", "Task already exists");
                }

                else
                {
                    combox_Name2.Items.Add(txt_Name.Text);
                    writer.WriteLine(txt_Name.Text);
                    writer.Flush();
                    writer.Dispose();
                }
            }

            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The file '" + txt_Name.Text + "' could not be located", "File could not be located");
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Quote: `using (StreamReader writer = `  :-)

Comment: Ah now I get it! Yeah thank you mate :) I put the writer.Dispose at the wrong place. Now I understand :) Thank you!

Comment: Yeah i adjusted it to `using(StreamReader sr =` like I had before ;) It works perfectly :)

Comment: The `File.Create(@"C:\Users\prakashv\Desktop\Test\test.txt");` is the problem not the using. Just delete the file and run it again.

Answer (score 1):

StreamWriter block you to do that you have to close it before using the file in the process or you have to do the changes in string and than when on process exist update the changes in to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close/dispose the writer. This also counts for the reader. You should get used to write it like this:

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt", true))
{
    // do your thing here.

}
```

This will close the stream at all time even when an exception is thrown inside.

This will be compiled like this:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt", true);
try
{
    // do your thing here.

}
finally
{
    writer.Dispose();
}
```

The actual problem lies here: **File.Create(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt");**

The file is created, but you didn't referenced the result. Declaration `public static FileStream Create(
    string path
)` This will *send* the result (FileStream) into the garbage and is disposed when the garbage collector collects it. You don't know when is happens. The file will remain open until it's garbagecollected. You can remove the whole line. If the file doesn't exists, don't execute the StreamReader part.

```
combox_Name2.Items.Clear();
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt"))
{
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt"))
    {
        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            combox_Name2.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget to remove the ! at the File.Exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still get the error :/ Maybe I do something wrong? If i use

 `using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt", true))
{
    // do your thing here.

}`

I have to put `try` into the `{}`. Is this correct? Please be patient I'm a newbie :)

Comment: No you don't need to write `try` in there, unless you want an exception handled there. If you put `try` within the `{}`, you can handle the exception when the file is still open. If you put the _try_ outside the `using(...)`, the file is closed while handing the exception. So the `using` won't handle exceptions, but always calls the `dispose` of the object inside before leaving the scope `{}`

Comment: But if I use `using`, I can't use `writer.WriteLine(combox_Name2.text);` for example because `StreamWriter writer` is in `( )`. I just don't get it >.<

Comment: read: using Statement (C# Reference) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Yeah the statement helped me to understand `using` and cause of the other answer I understand now where I did the mistake. Thank you for supporting :)

Comment: No it's the: File.Create(@"C:\Users\rs\Desktop\Test\test.txt"); that is blocking your read/write, this will only occure when there is no file present.

Comment: Oh I didn't noticed your edit. Mh, if I close `StreamWriter` it works fine. I will check your suggestion :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Always place objects that implements the IDisposable interface within

```
using(IDisposable object goes here)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

In your case the StreamWriter object.